# Custom page callback gave 404 but the page content is correct

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a page callback that shows users' related content and displays a custom login form if user is not logged in.

The site worked in another server, but today I migrated it to this laptop, and the page gave 404, while the content is as normal. I have check Apache's configuration, it is OK and other internal paths worked well.

```
function camp_orders(){
    global $user;
    if($user->uid > 0){
        // some code here 
        return theme("camp_user_orders", array('camps' => $camp_types));
    }else{
        return drupal_get_form('camp_mobile_login');
    }
}
```

## update

The clean url system works well. The page is rendered correctly, but the response code is 404, and the form cannot be submitted.
However the response code is correct (200) when I use query parameters like `?q=path`.

Comment: Is the custom module installed?

Comment: @J.Reynolds It is enabled and the rendered html is correct, only the response code is wrong.

Comment: check .htaccess may be some rule is restricting

Comment: @ShreyaShetty I have never modified .htaccess, and clean URL works for other internal paths.